# Uploading images from website in a discord bot

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

`await ctx.send(file=discord.File(r'www.abc.com/wal1.jpg')`
Its ain't working this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On discord links to files are getting converted to that files automatically, so you should get away with:

```py
await ctx.send("www.abc.com/wal1.jpg")
```

If you really want to send a **file** you can download it and then send it using `discord.File()` method. Something like this:

```py
response = requests.get("www.abc.com/wal1.jpg")
with open(f"img.jpg", "wb") as file:
    file.write(response.content)
await ctx.send(file=discord.File("img.jpg"))
```

Comment: yep. Upvoted. OP should have been more clear, because they edited it and my answer seem odd